# My jungle, corruption, and hallowed biomes all spawned in the same place

Tags: terraria-console

My jungle, corruption, and hallowed biomes all spawned in the same place, so my world is only 1% Hallowed and it's not increasing, however I need a hallowed Biome so I can get the Storm Bow, any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making the [Dryad NPC](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad) move in, during Hardmode, you can buy [Hallowed Seeds](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hallowed_Seeds) from her for 20 silver to create [the Hallow biome](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Hallow).

If when you get enough to make a biome and already have the [Steampunker NPC](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Steampunker), you can make him move to a house inside the Hallow and buy [Clentaminator and Blue Solution](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clentaminator) to spread it faster.

Comment: That'd work for the surface, but I need underground Hallowed for the Souls of Light

Comment: The hallowed seed makes dirt become hallowed. Make a Hallow biome at surface, make a house for the Steampunker, go underground with a Clentaminator and tons of Blue Solution and just go wild with it

Comment: And as far as I know, there is nothing stopping you from planting the seeds directly underground. It just need to be planted on dirt. You can make a hollow underground and put dirt there to make it suitable for the seeds.

Comment: But I need the Storm Bow for the Mechanical Bosses, which you need to kill for the Steampunker

Comment: I'll try making a dirt area and making it hallowed when I get home

Answer (score 0):

The Hallow and Corruption Biomes can spread by grass and stone proximity. So, in addition to the Clentaminator mentioned above, if you collect the pearlstone and place it near regular stone in another area, it will start to convert and spread the regular stone to pearlstone. For corruption, it works the same way but with ebonstone. I think the pearlstone will also convert regular grass to hallowed grass.

This will eventually reach down into the underground, but you could help it by digging a channel down.

Also, most biomes in Terraria are based on the surrounding blocks. So, you can create an artificial hallow biome by simply placing a minimum number of blocks (I think it's 80) of the correct type. e.g. Plant jungle grass seeds on a pile of mud, and when it spreads far enough you'll have a jungle biome.

Comment: Quick side question: Will the Hallow overpower the Corruption?

Comment: From a quick couple of google searches, no. Corruption and Hallow can only spread to regular blocks, not previously converted blocks. But the wiki does say that hallow spreads more slowly than corruption/crimson.